# A stochastic process $X$ with values in a separable Banach space $E$ is a martingale iff $f(X)$ is a martingale for all $f\in E^\ast$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-analysis

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a filtration on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$
- $(E,\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|)$ be a separable Banach space and $E^*$ be the dual space of $E$
- $(X_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be an $\mathcal F$-adapted $E$-valued stochastic process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$

I want to show that $X$ is a $\mathcal F$-martingale $\Leftrightarrow$ $$f(X)\text{ is a }\mathcal F\text{-martingale}\;\;\;\text{for all }f\in E^*\tag 1\;.$$

---

Using

> **Lemma**$\;\;\;$Let $Y$ be a $E$-valued Bochner integrable random variable $\Rightarrow$ $$\operatorname E[f(Y)]=f\left(\operatorname E[Y]\right)\;\;\;\text{for all }f\in E^*\tag 2\;.$$

it's easy to prove "$\Rightarrow$":

- Let $f\in E^*$
- $f$ is continuous $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is $\mathcal B(E)$-measurable $\Rightarrow$ $f(X_t)$ is $\mathcal A$-measurable and $$\operatorname E\left[\left|f(X_t)\right|\right]\le\sup_E|f|<\infty$$ for all $t\ge 0$ since $f$ is bounded $\Rightarrow$ $f(X)$ is integrable
- Let $t\ge s\ge 0$ and $A\in\mathcal F_s$ $\Rightarrow$
  \begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
  \operatorname E\left[1_Af(X_t)\right]&=\operatorname E\left[f(1_AX_t)\right]\\
  &\stackrel{(2)}=f\left(\operatorname E\left[1_AX_t\right]\right)\\
  &=f\left(\operatorname E\left[1_AX_s\right]\right)\\
  &\stackrel{(2)}=\operatorname E\left[f(1_AX_s)\right]\\
  &=\operatorname E\left[1_Af(X_s)\right]
  \end{split}
  \end{equation}
  since $X$ is a $\mathcal F$-martingale

> How can we prove "$\Leftarrow$"?

Answer (score 3):

Using the lemma, you can prove a conditional version of it:

$f(E(X_t|\mathcal F_s)) = E(f(X_t)|\mathcal F_s)\tag{1}$

Since $f(X_t)$ is martingale, we have

$f(E(X_t|\mathcal F_s)) = f(X_s)$

By Hahn-Banach Theorem,

$E(X_t|\mathcal F_s)= X_s$